# IISRESET On IIS 6.0 failing

Tags: iis, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I am trying to do a reset on IIS 6.0 from the command line and I get this message below, all the services are up and running, googled for a solution, tells me to reinstall IIS 6.0, which I tried so many times. Any idea what is the problem?
Using windows server 2003.

```
Attempting stop...
Internet services successfully stopped
Attempting start...
Restart attempt failed.
IIS Admin Service or a service dependent on IIS Admin is not active.  It most likely failed to start, which may mean that it's disabled.
```

Comment: Ensure the IIS Admin service is running (and installed).

Comment: i did verify the IIS ADMIN service and it always shows as running, even after iis reset fails.

Comment: This would be better as a comment than an answer, but I don't have that privilege. Do you see any specific errors in the application or system logs? Try performing a stop/start in services.msc: Does it give you a more specific error?

Comment: Are there error messages in the Application or System event logs related to W3SVC or IISADM?

Comment: no there are no errors in any eventvwr logs, i also tried to do logman but didn;t spit out anything that was useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-part answer:

0) You reinstalled IIS despite it working? Just as a safety note, reapply the latest SP and patch for it. Just in case the binary versions are out of whack.

1) Don't IISReset. Why are you IISResetting? Are you /NoForce ing it?

2) Have you identified whether any other services are stopped? WWW Publishing, FTP Publishing, SMTP Publishing, and so on? That'd be my guess as to what the error means.

Comment: no it was not working when i reinstalled. when i say its not working, i mean it would work but when you do issreset you would get the msg above.so i thought there must be a bigger problem here. 

to apply any changes i have made i do iisreset. no i am not doing /noForce

no i have not checked otehr services, only service that is hossted on that IIS is WWW, so i will check than one now

Comment: it looks like WIndwos remomet Managemnt starts and goes down

Comment: I think you're looking for a dependent service, which you might be able to spot through services.msc on the dependencies tab. As a rule, you shouldn't IISReset unless you're making global changes to every app pool, which will typically recycle (i.e. kill and restart) all the app pools "cleanly" anyway. If that works, and IISReset is still flaky, it doesn't matter.

Comment: if anything is not working wouldn't that mean something is not working... when i check status of iis using iisreset /status it shows the windows management is down

Comment: I'm asking whether it's just IISReset that's broken, and a) it's recommended not to use it outside of specific circumstances, and b) it doesn't affect your application anyway, it might not be a meaningful failure. Do you use WinRM?

Comment: the service is there for WinRM, but it doesn't start, it says some service start and stop when there is noting to do, when i try start it

Comment: no i don't use WinRm on that server, not sure if any dependednt process for IIS users it.